# C# - invalid token '' in class struct or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, selenium

I've checked all the other questions asked here about the "Invalid Token ' ' in..." here, but none have been able to apply to my issue.  And yes, the error list gave me an empty single quote to specify the invalid token.  Below is my code (the namespace is not the actual one I'm using fyi):

```
namespace Testing.SeleniumUITests.PageObjects
  {


      public abstract class PageObject
      {
         public void TakeScreenshot(string filename)
         {
            try
            {
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Screenshots\" + filename + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //var i2 = new Bitmap(ss);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
   ​ }
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the method.  Am I missing a certain reference or any other 'using' namespaces?

Comment: is this the entirety of the file?

Comment: no, this isn't the entire file.  The class I put this in had no errors inside it until I put this method in there, than the error message comes up.  When I click on the error message, it takes me to the 2nd to closing curly bracket.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the problem has been solved.  When I copied the code into notepad, saved it and then opened it again, there was a '?' at the end of the curly bracket.  In visual studio, there was no visible ? there.  So I guess it was just hidden or something.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Try to clean your solution and rebuild it

Comment: @StriterAlfa I was able to figure it out already and answered my question below.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like there was a hidden character.  I received the code from a co-worker of mine thru messaging website and I guess that site just added that extra hidden character.

If anyone has this issue in the future where you have an empty invalid token error message, copy and paste the suspect code block into notepad and save it.  Open it again and you should see the hidden character you couldn't see before.

Comment: It also happened to a co-worker of mine when we exchanged codes through teams. An invisible character might have been added as we pass around code snippets.